# Download image with rust fails (image corrupted)

Tags: image, rust, download

I am trying to download image/file with rust, works like a wget.
I followed this https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/rust-cookbook/web/clients/download.html#download-a-file-to-a-temporary-directory

But a temp file isn't created, not sure why. If you remove the temp folder part, a png file is created but cannot be read. Seems corrupted.

How do I download a binary file with Rust? I could not find a good solution online.

Comment: Are you using that code exactly? Or have you made changes? If so, please include your version.

Comment: You probably don't want to use reqwest's `.text()` method for binary data...

Comment: I used exactly the same code. Including that image url.

Comment: Does it work on your computers?
I know `.text()` is usually not used in this scenario, but that's how the sample code does it.

Comment: I get the same behavior. Files created by the tempfile crate delete themselves when they are dropped, which is why the "file isn't created". And if you avoid that, you get a corrupted png because `.text()` replaces non-utf8 bytes with a replacement character.

Comment: You should probably file an issue with the authors that the `.text()` part is deficient (since it does mention that the temporary folder is removed on exit). It should probably be replaced with `.bytes()`.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

Use `.bytes` instead of `.text()`, and has to wrap the bytes inside `std::io::Cursor`.

Since temp file is removed on exit, I commented one line out to see the resulting image in cwd.

```rust
    let mut content =  Cursor::new(response.bytes().await?);
    copy(&mut content, &mut dest)?;
```

### Complete Solution

```rust
use error_chain::error_chain;
use std::io::copy;
use std::fs::File;
use tempfile::Builder;
use std::io::Cursor;

error_chain! {
     foreign_links {
         Io(std::io::Error);
         HttpRequest(reqwest::Error);
     }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let tmp_dir = Builder::new().prefix("example").tempdir()?;
    let target = "https://www.rust-lang.org/logos/rust-logo-512x512.png";
    let response = reqwest::get(target).await?;

    let mut dest = {
        let fname = response
            .url()
            .path_segments()
            .and_then(|segments| segments.last())
            .and_then(|name| if name.is_empty() { None } else { Some(name) })
            .unwrap_or("tmp.bin");

        println!("file to download: '{}'", fname);
        // let fname = tmp_dir.path().join(fname);
        println!("will be located under: '{:?}'", fname);
        File::create(fname)?
    };
    // let content =  response.text().await?;
    // copy(&mut content.as_bytes(), &mut dest)?;

    let mut content =  Cursor::new(response.bytes().await?);
    copy(&mut content, &mut dest)?;
    Ok(())
}
```